# Bucket sort in Rust

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rust

First of all, the code:

```
struct Bucket<H, V> where H: Ord
{
    hash: H,
    values: Vec<V>
}

impl<H, V> Bucket<H, V> where H: Ord {
    fn new(hash: H) -> Bucket<H, V> {
        Bucket {
            hash: hash,
            values: vec![],
        }
    }
}

pub fn bucket_sort<T, F, H>(values: Vec<T>, hasher: F) -> Vec<T>
    where T: Ord, F: Fn(&T) -> H, H: Ord
{

    let mut buckets: Vec<Bucket<H, T>> = vec![];

    for value in values.into_iter() {
        let hash = hasher(&value);
        match buckets.binary_search_by(|bucket| bucket.hash.cmp(&hash)) {
            Ok(index) => {
                buckets[index].values.push(value);
            },
            Err(index) => {
                let mut bucket = Bucket::new(hash);
                bucket.values.push(value);
                buckets.insert(index, bucket);
            }
        }
    }

    let mut sorted_values = Vec::new();
    for bucket in buckets.into_iter() {
        let mut bucket = bucket;
        bucket.values.sort();
        sorted_values.extend(bucket.values);
    }
    sorted_values
}

#[test]
fn test_bucket_sort() {
    let values = vec![5, 10, 2, 99, 32, 1, 7, 9, 92, 135, 0, 54];
    let sorted_values = bucket_sort(values, |int| int / 10);
    assert_eq!(sorted_values, vec![0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 32, 54, 92, 99, 135]);
}
```

The thing that bothers me about this implementation is that it's destructive: `bucket_sort` takes ownership of a vector, and builds another one. I first tried to implement a bucket sort with this signature:

```
pub fn bucket_sort<T, F, H>(values: &[T], hasher: F) -> Vec<T>
where T: Ord, F: Fn(&T) -> H, H: Ord
```

But I realized that passing a slice means that:

- either sorting must happen in place
- or elements must implement `Copy`

`Copy`-ing is too restrictive and probably inefficient on a large number of values, and I don't know if it's possible to implement in-place sorting with bucket sort.

Apart from this, are there any obvious style/performance flaws in this implementation?

Comment: Hooray more Rust questions! Hope you get the review you want, and welcome to Code Review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great work! One thing that stuck out to me was the use of `extend`; that shows that you've looked through the API docs to see what's available. Most of the time, people start out by just `push`ing all the elements from one vector to the other.

> But I realized that passing a slice means that:
>
> - either sorting must happen in place
> - or elements must implement `Copy`

This analysis is correct, congratulations! In fact, this is something I like about Rust's type system. If I hand a method a `&mut [T]`, then I know that it is very likely that it will be doing something in-place, presumably in an efficient manner.

> `Copy`-ing is [...] probably inefficient on a large number of values

Types that implement `Copy` are those that be be semantically duplicated by copying bits but not executing any additional code. Generally, this is something that processors are good at. Types that are `Clone`, on the other hand, require some additional computation to occur when they are duplicated. These are the ones you want to be careful about duplicating needlessly. In general, I wouldn't worry about doing *some* copies.

Your point about `Copy` potentially being overly restrictive is quite valid though.

---

1. `where` clauses go on a separate line, and each additional restriction also goes on a separate line. This helps readability and understanding as those restrictions can dramatically change how a function should be called.
2. Use trailing commas just about everywhere in Rust.
3. I prefer to not add type restrictions on structs or methods that don't need them.
4. I prefer to not use `into_iter` when I can just pass the collection directly to something that accepts an `IntoIterator`.
5. Pick one of `Vec::new` or `vec![]` and be consistent with it.
6. Prefer `for mut bucket in buckets` instead of rebinding the variable just to add mutability.
7. Extend `Bucket::new` to take a value. You don't really need the ability to create an empty bucket.
8. The `match` arms can be one-lined.
9. `flat_map` and `collect` can be used to glom all of the intermediate vectors into one.
10. It's OK to compare a `Vec<T>` against an array of `T`. Use this in the tests to avoid needlessly allocating another vector.

```
struct Bucket<H, V> {
    hash: H,
    values: Vec<V>,
}

impl<H, V> Bucket<H, V> {
    fn new(hash: H, value: V) -> Bucket<H, V> {
        Bucket {
            hash: hash,
            values: vec![value],
        }
    }
}

pub fn bucket_sort<T, F, H>(values: Vec<T>, hasher: F) -> Vec<T>
    where T: Ord,
          F: Fn(&T) -> H,
          H: Ord
{
    let mut buckets: Vec<Bucket<H, T>> = Vec::new();

    for value in values {
        let hash = hasher(&value);
        match buckets.binary_search_by(|bucket| bucket.hash.cmp(&hash)) {
            Ok(index) => buckets[index].values.push(value),
            Err(index) => buckets.insert(index, Bucket::new(hash, value)),
        }
    }

    buckets.into_iter().flat_map(|mut bucket| {
        bucket.values.sort();
        bucket.values
    }).collect()
}

#[test]
fn test_bucket_sort() {
    let values = vec![5, 10, 2, 99, 32, 1, 7, 9, 92, 135, 0, 54];
    let sorted_values = bucket_sort(values, |int| int / 10);
    assert_eq!(sorted_values,
               [0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 32, 54, 92, 99, 135]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed review, especially wrt to `Copy` and `Clone`. `flat_map` is great!

Comment: Ah, also thanks for #6, it did bother me ;)